# How can I make this VBA loop (for each cell, copy paste) faster?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a piece of code that is taking up a large amount of the actual runtime. It seems like this loop actually makes Excel unresponsive at times (not 100% sure about this, but this seems to me the most likely culprit when I stepped through the code). Anyways, I want to optimize this piece of code so it doesn't take so long.

Some background:

**EDIT:** application.screenupdating is set to false
Sheets(1) = RawData
Sheets(2) = AreaTable
j=2 before entering the loop
rng is the range including all values in sheet1 column CJ minus the header 
In sheet1 column CJ is a list of ComponentNames that I want to loop through. For each ComponentName, I want to filter column AL and copy paste (transpose) all the visible values in column AL (there will always be at least >1 value) to Sheets(2).
There are usually around 1000-1200 ComponentNames and anywhere from 10-240 values (the same values that I'm copy pasting to sheet2) for each ComponentName.

```
For Each cell In rng
    ComponentName = cell.Value
    RawData.Range("A:CJ").AutoFilter field:=17, Criteria1:=ComponentName
    RawData.Range("AL2", Range("AL2").End(xlDown)).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    AreaTable.Range("B" & j).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
    j = j + 1
Next cell
```

What changes can I make to this loop to get the process done faster?

Comment: `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` before the start of the loop, and `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` after you exit the loop

Comment: Thanks! I do toggle screenpdating at the beginning and end of my codes usually, and it does help. This particular macro though still hangs up even with the screenupdating set to false while executing. Will edit my original post to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may try something like that:

```
Dim outputVal As Variant, chkRng As Variant, valRng As Variant
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
With rawdata
  k = .Cells(Rows.Count, 38).End(xlUp).Row
  chkRng = .Range("Q2:Q" & k).Value
  valRng = .Range("AL2:AL" & k).Value
  ReDim outputVal(rng.Count, 0)

  For Each cell In rng.Value
    k = 0
    For i = LBound(chkRng) To UBound(chkRng)
      If chkRng(i, 1) = cell Then
        outputVal(j, k) = valRng(i, 1)
        k = k + 1
        If k > UBound(outputVal, 2) Then ReDim Preserve outputVal(rng.Count, k)
      End If
    Next
    j = j + 1
  Next
End With
With areatable: .Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(rng.Count + 1, UBound(outputVal, 2) + 2)).Value = outputVal: End With
```

pls test it with a copy... not having the real workbook may completely mess everything up... but it will probably end in an error...

pls try it and then tell what went wrong :)

**EDIT**
tested it with a small table and it worked perfectly (and also pretty fast), however: without a small example-workbook its hard to check if it will also work for you

**EDIT2**

the way it works: when looking for *speed* you need to know that everything a sheet need to do is slow. so the first part simply gets all the values to check/copy whatever and put them in variables (which is much faster in reading/writing). (`chkRng` and `valRng`)
then i generate a variable for the outputs (`outputVal`)

knowing there is only 1 value to check (filter) i also can compare the column with your `cell`. and everytime it finds a match the other value (same position) is put into the output-value (and resizing the value if needed).

lastly it pastes the outputvalue in the desired range in one step.

main downsides:
 - no format will be copied (only the values, but could be changed to also copy formulas, while there is no need here)
 - you need to know the exact range (to small and values will be missing / to big and an errorcode will be in each cell outside of the variable-range)

Comment: Dirk, it looks like your code works for me with a few modifications (I added +1 to each of the rng.Count after the ReDim statements -- value of j was causing out of range error when it hit the last ComponentName). One thing I can't seem to figure out though is why it starts pasting at Row3 of Sheet(2) instead of Row2? I'll take your answer (thanks!), do you think I could trouble you to comment in your code explaining what you're doing so I can learn a little bit?

Comment: @YOO629 `j` needs to be 0 at the beginning (adding `j = 0` in front of `For Each...` should avoid the error and also the output should start at row 2... also added some explanations to my code... if you need to know something in detail just ask :)

Comment: @YOO629 but i'd like to know how much faster this solution is (if it is faster)... just for the future if similar questions pop up :)

Comment: So when I was running my test case with ~1259 Components and 20 names, it took about 30 seconds on average. Your solution takes about 3-4 seconds (!!).

Answer (score 2):

Build an array of the `ComponentName` values and filter & copy/paste once instead of a thousand times.

```
Dim v As Long, vCOMPNAMEs As Variant

With rng
    ReDim vCOMPNAMEs(.Count)
    For v = LBound(vCOMPNAMEs) To UBound(vCOMPNAMEs)
        vCOMPNAMEs(v) = rng.cells(v + 1).Value2
    Next v
End With

With RawData
    .Range("A:CJ").AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:=vCOMPNAMEs, Operator:=xlFilterValues
    .Range("AL2", Range("AL2").End(xlDown)).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    AreaTable.Range("B" & j).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
    j = j + 1   '<~~?????
End With
```

Comment: Maybe I have no idea what is going on but it looks to me like it all goes to the same place, just shifted down one row for every new filter. I've collected all of the filters into one so one copy & paste is all that is needed.

Comment: but you will get one list with all values that match at least one filter and not one listfor each filter... that would be a different output, not?

Comment: No, this is a good answer, you might want to add a sort at the end, but the results should be the same, you'll get all the records that match your various filter in one shot..but I still suggest turning off calculation before you run it :)

Comment: i think i missed something... how will `.Range("AL2", Range("AL2").End(xlDown)).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy` grant multiple columns? (or rows after transpose)... i never said that this is wrong or bad or something like that... i just dont get how it will work...

Comment: because his filter condition includes all values in rng, so every row that would be selected in the one by one iteration is available in one shot..so all the applicable rows get moved over in one operation, if the results are then sorted, you get the same result

Comment: i need to admit that im just unable to understand it... ive tested it and only get 1 row with all values... also when clicking the set filter in column Q excel crashes... however: as long as it works for other ppl, better ignore me :D

Comment: @DirkReichel I'm actually having the same issue. Firstly, my excel gives me a runtime error 1004 saying that the copy area and the paste area aren't the same size. That's not a big deal. When I do paste it, it's just one long row/column depending if I transpose it or not.

Comment: @YOO629 unfortunately i can't help with that issue :( you may try some of the other answers... however, jeeped often does real cool stuff i don't understand, so i'm still hoping he will explain how to make it work :)

Answer (score 1):

Turn calculation off before you run this, because everytime you filter, it recalculates the workbook, and if there are a lot of formulas then that will eat away at your processors:

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
For Each cell In Rng
    ComponentName = cell.Value
    RawData.Range("A:CJ").AutoFilter field:=17, Criteria1:=ComponentName
    RawData.Range("AL2", Range("AL2").End(xlDown)).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    AreaTable.Range("B" & j).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
    j = j + 1
Next cell
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

Comment: The RawData sheet itself does not have any formulas at all. It's just a spreadsheet of names and numbers. I've been timing my code with and without your suggestion and it doesn't seem to provide a significant change in runtime.

Answer (score 0):

David's suggestion is what I was going to post, that will help a lot. Also, try this (not assigning ComponentName). Untested, but should work:

```
For Each cell In rng
    RawData.Range("A:CJ").AutoFilter field:=17, Criteria1:=cell.Value
    RawData.Range("AL2", Range("AL2").End(xlDown)).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    AreaTable.Range("B" & j).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
    j = j + 1
Next cell
```

It might also be faster to store into an array... unfortunately I don't know how many cells you're copying in... but I'll assume you're copying in 2 cells in this example, change as per your needs. Anyway, you could store results into an array and then spit out results all at once, like this:

```
dim arr(300000,1)
For Each cell In rng
    RawData.Range("A:CJ").AutoFilter field:=17, Criteria1:=cell.Value
    arr(j,0) = RawData.Range("AL2")
    arr(j,1) = RawData.Range("AL2").offset(1,0)
    ' etc.... do this for each (or create a loop to capture everything)
    j = j + 1
Next cell

for j_ctr = 1 to j
    AreaTable.Range("B" & j).value=arr(j_ctr,0)
    AreaTable.Range("B" & j+1).value=arr(j_ctr,1)
next
```

unless the expensive part is the autofiltering... any way to avoid this?

Comment: its the calculation that slows down the autofiltering..see answer above